# Gold Job Icons on Map

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Search for this and couldn't find anything. In online mode on my map usually all the job icons are blue. Well I have one parachute mission on the map that the icon is gold. I have been logged off and back on a couple times and every time it seems to be the same parachute job. Does anyone know what it means and why it is gold?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason it is gold is because you bookmarked it through Rockstar Social Club; all bookmarked jobs (missions, survival, deathmatches, races, etc.) are highlighted in gold.

If you log into your Rockstar Social Club account, go to the GTA V section, then go to "GTA Online", you can find a list of your Bookmarked Jobs:

[image]

There you can remove any bookmarked jobs.

Also, if you open your map and highlight that icon with your cursor, it should say "Bookmarked (*Job Type*)".

Hope this helps!